# Remote Debugging of .net application from localmachine for code hosted on Citrix Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, hosting, citrix

I am trying to do remote debugging of my asp.net code which is hosted on a Citrix server, I am not able to attach the IIS process running in my citrix to visual studio on my machine. I only see wfica32.exe in available options, is there any way i can get the iis process (w3wp.exe) running on my remote citrix server, so that i can debug the application

Comment: in the entry point of your code or if it's a service in the OnStart try adding the following code 
`System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();`

Comment: I have tried, but this doesnt work :(

Comment: You need to install Visual Studio's remote debugging tools on the server. Go find the version of the tools suitable for your version of VS.

Comment: Is there any way i can do without installing , our client isn't comfortable for installing it on their server